# How many ways are there to measure time?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, stopwatch

So far, I've counted three ways to measure the current time or time differences in C#:

- [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Environment.TickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

And the following types that represent time/timespan measurements:

- [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

Are there any others?

---

Also, the definition of "Tick" seems to be inconsistent. For example:

- `Environment.TickCount` measure 1-millisecond intervals.
- `DateTime.Ticks` and `TimeSpan.Ticks` measure 100-nanosecond intervals.
- `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks` are based on `Stopwatch.Frequency` and the exact interval can vary from system to system.

*What's up with that?*

---

Also, what differences are there between the various time measurement methods/types, in what circumstances should one be used over the other?

Comment: What do you need to know that is not in the documentation for each of the things you have linked to?

Comment: What is time? A relative human construct...

Comment: "Are there any others?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's up with that?

The first sentence of each of the documentation pages you link to give a pretty clear description of their purpose (emphasis added):

- [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)

> the **current date and time** on this computer, expressed as the local time.

- [`Environment.TickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed **since the system started**.

- [`StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure **elapsed time**.

- [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents **an instant in time**, typically expressed as a date and time of day.

- [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents **a time interval**.

(a difference between two points in time)

So `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are not interchangeable, and more than `Location` and `Distance` are.  They are *related* but represent different things.

If any of those are not clear, or you need further clarification, please say *specifically* what you're confused about.

---

> Also, the definition of "Tick" seems to be inconsistent.

Because they're define _within the context of where they're defined.  There's not an "industry-standard" definition for "ticks" that I'm aware of.  Some types (like `Stopwatch`) sacrifice range for greater precision, while others (like `DateTime`) allow for much larger ranges but cannot be millisecond-precise.

---

> Are there any others?

One that you haven't mentioned is:

- [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Generates an event after a set interval, with an option to generate recurring events.

Again, it *serves a different purpose*.  It's designed to do something at regular intervals.

I'm not sure how broad your scope is to know if there are "any others".  If you have a *specific* need that isn't met by one of these classes then add that to your question.